# Get constant SALT from encrypted and clear text values

Tags: salt, brute-force, cracking

I have a constant SALT that is appended to every cookie before it is encrypted with sha512. If I know the clear text and the final encrypted values of more than one cookie, is it possible to use a tool like john the ripper to guess the salt value?

The answers I found on the internet talk about finding the password, but i'm interested in finding the salt.

Comment: How big is the salt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer:

**No you can't.**

---

Reasons:

1. First of all sha512 is a hashfunction. You can't "decrypt" hashfunctions. If it would be able to do this, sha512 would not be safe.
2. Days ago google found the first collision in 6,610 CPU-Years.

   Source: [First sha512 Hashcollsion](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/02/23/google_first_sha1_collision/)

   (This is not an attack!) They used an amount of distributed systems. So a normal program like john-the-ripper wouldn't be able to do this.

Comment: Actually 6,500 years of CPU computation to complete the attack first phase plus 110 years of GPU computation to complete the second phase.

Comment: yeah sorry i just want to say that it is not possible today

Answer (score 1):

SHA512 is not encryption.

It would require a brute force attack across the salt range, if the salt is just a few characters or bytes the attack would easily succeed.

Depending on the usage an HMAC may be a better choice than just appending a salt, there are attacks (depending usage) on a concatenated salt.

If you use the same salt it will can discovered by the attacker who gains access to the system. A better method is to use a random salt with an HMAC and prepend the salt to the hash value, then it does not need to be secret. This assumes you need to be able to recompute the same hash from the same data

For passwords, where more security is needed, using a hash function with a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.